# Remove bad character if at beginning of column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I have a `DF` of emails where the first character in the email is occasionally a symbol. I am trying to remove it if it exists.

```text
+--------------------+
|       Email        |
+--------------------+
|bob@gmail.com       |
|*steve@yahoo.com    |
|leeroy@hotmail.com  |
|@grant@gmail.com    |
+--------------------+
```

The final `df` would look like this:

```text
+--------------------+
|       Email        |
+--------------------+
|bob@gmail.com       |
|steve@yahoo.com     |
|leeroy@hotmail.com  |
|grant@gmail.com     |
+--------------------+
```

Is there a way to do this efficiently?

Comment: You can use regex

Answer (score 3):

Using `regexp_replace` function should do the job.

You can adapt the regex if needed. Here it removes all non-alphanumeric characters from the beginning.

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("Email", regexp_replace(col("Email"), "^[^a-zA-z0-9]", ""))

df1.show()

//+------------------+
//|             Email|
//+------------------+
//|     bob@gmail.com|
//|   steve@yahoo.com|
//|leeroy@hotmail.com|
//|   grant@gmail.com|
//+------------------+
```